# Definition of Schwartz space

Tags: functional-analysis, definition, schwartz-space

We have the following definition of Schwartz space $S(\mathbb{R}^k)$:  we tell that the function $\psi: \mathbb{R}^k \to \mathbb{C}$ is in $S(\mathbb{R}^k)$ iff 
1. $\psi \in C^{\infty}(\mathbb{R}^k)$ and 2. for all $m \in \mathbb{N}$ and for all $\alpha \in \mathbb{N}^k$, there exists $C_{m, \alpha}(\psi) >0$ such as $\forall x \in \mathbb{R}^k, (1+|x|^2)^m |D^\alpha \psi(x)| \leq C_{m,\alpha}(\psi)$.

Please can you help me to prove the following proposition: we tell that $\psi: \mathbb{R}^k \to \mathbb{C}$ is in $S(\mathbb{R}^k)$ iff 1. $\psi \in C^\infty(\mathbb{R}^k)$ and 2. forall $l \in\mathbb{N}$ and for all $\alpha \in \mathbb{N}^k$ the function $x \to |x|^l D^{\alpha} \psi(x)$ is bounded.

Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: Hint: To show that Def. 2 implies Def.1, use the binomial theorem from algebra. To show that Def. 1 implies Def. 2, use the inequality $\xi \leq 1 + \xi^{2}$, valid for all real numbers $\xi \geq 0$ and once more the binomial theorem.

Answer (score 0):

Definition 1 implies definition 2 because for each $l\in\mathbb N$ and $\alpha\in \mathbb N^k$, 
$$
\left\lvert |x|^l D^{\alpha} \psi(x)\right\rvert\leqslant \left(1+\left\lvert x\right\rvert^2\right)^{l}\left\lvert D^{\alpha} \psi(x)\right\rvert\leqslant C_{l,\alpha}\left(\psi\right).
$$
For the opposite direction, let $m\in\mathbb N$ and $\alpha\in \mathbb N^k$. Using the binomial formula, the following equality holds
$$
(1+|x|^2)^m |D^\alpha \psi(x)| =\sum_{j=0}^m\binom mj|x|^{2j}|D^\alpha \psi(x)| 
$$
hence 
$$\sup_{x\in\mathbb R^k}
(1+|x|^2)^m |D^\alpha \psi(x)| \leqslant \sum_{j=0}^m\binom mj\sup_{t\in\mathbb R^k}|t|^{2j}|D^\alpha \psi(t)| \lt+\infty.
$$